# How should I implement accurate pitch-detection in Java for Android phones?

Tags: java, android, signal-processing, frequency, pitch

I want to develop an application that would require accurate pitch-detection for musical instruments through the Android phone's microphone. Most suggestions I read of involve using Fast Fourier Transforms (FFT), but they mentioned it having issues with accuracy and processing power (considering it should run smoothly on a smartphone). One answer suggested a 5Hz error margin, which would be quite noticeable in the low frequency tone range. If the error is logarithmic rather than static in nature, the error margin from each note should be less than 10 Cents (1 Cent=100th root of a semitone, 1,200th root of an octave), which would be <(1.005792941...).

Are those issues correct? If so, are there better approaches for pitch detection? Are there open source libraries that do this, or will I have to write the algorithm on my own (while aiming to accurately detect possibly more than one note per second)? I have a basic Java knowledge.

Also, what are the expected limitations for frequency range sensitivity of the average smartphone's microphone?

Comment: Have you tried specialized libraries, such as [aubio](http://aubio.org)? It is successfully used in Android apps.

Comment: Well, I haven't got into writing any of it at the moment. I did mention that I'm on a rather rusty+rookie knowledge scale at the moment, so it might sound a bit over the top, but anyway: I see that this library is written in C. Assuming that suites my needs, I should port it to Java?

Comment: No, you can use C libraries on Android (see [Android NDK](https://developer.android.com/tools/sdk/ndk/index.html)).

Comment: Your primary challenge will be coming up with a sound algorithm, not dealing with the Android device.

Comment: Well, can it be implemented in its native C inside an App written in Java? If I can implement this library and it is accurate then that might work out, but it should be able to also discern the heard octave as well.