# How to get voice frequency from current time of voice on android

Tags: android, command, android-library, voice-recognition

I am an android developer. I want to made an android app with voice command (Not using Google voice). Is there any library on Android platform that i can use for processing voice on android or have any class on android library. Actually i want to find out current time voice frequency. Like if i record 
a 5 second voice, i want to find out frequency of every millisecond of the voice.
Or please tell me what is the best way of making a voice command android app.

Below is an example of the similar app.

https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.saycheese&hl=en

Comment: Already asked http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23589911/how-should-i-implement-accurate-pitch-detection-in-java-for-android-phones and http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26831369/android-app-pitch-recognition?rq=1

Comment: Also http://stackoverflow.com/questions/33198685/most-simple-way-to-get-pitch-of-microphone-audio-input-on-android-phones. You need to google for keyword "pitch".

Comment: And, detection of "cheese" is better implemented without pitch. It is better to take speech recognition or detection library or build GMM-based voice detector.